# Problem with coordinates transformation using geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to convert some LAT, LON coordinates points to a national grid. I would be grateful for your help as I spent hours searching for an answer.

The console in anaconda/spyder gives an error:
`RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'`

My code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import shapely

postcodeDF = pd.DataFrame({'lp': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                           'nazwa': ['Aleksandrów Kujawski', 'Aleksandrów Łódzki', 'Alwernia', 'Andrychów', 'Annopol'],
                           'szer_geo': [52.875, 51.820278, 50.06861, 49.855278, 50.885278],
                           'dlug_geo': [18.694722, 19.305, 19.54194, 19.345, 21.854]})
crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
geometry = [shapely.geometry.Point(xy) for xy in zip(postcodeDF['dlug_geo'], postcodeDF['szer_geo'])]

postcodeGDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(postcodeDF,
                               crs = crs,
                               geometry = geometry)

postcodeGDF['geometry'] = postcodeGDF['geometry'].to_crs('+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')

postcodeGDF.plot()
```

`print(gpd.show_versions())` gives:

```
SYSTEM INFO
-----------
python     : 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable : C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
machine    : Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

GEOS, GDAL, PROJ INFO
---------------------
GEOS       : None
GEOS lib   : None
GDAL       : 2.3.3
GDAL data dir: None
PROJ       : 0.5.20
PROJ data dir: 

PYTHON DEPENDENCIES
-------------------
geopandas  : 0.6.3
pandas     : 0.25.1
fiona      : 1.8.4
numpy      : 1.16.5
shapely    : 1.6.4.post2
rtree      : 0.9.4
pyproj     : 1.9.6
matplotlib : 3.1.1
mapclassify: None
pysal      : None
geopy      : None
psycopg2   : None
```

The console displays such information:

```
runfile('D:/Dydaktyka/SIPwT (1z2)/test.py', wdir='D:/Dydaktyka/SIPwT (1z2)')
0    POINT (18.69472 52.87500)
1    POINT (19.30500 51.82028)
2    POINT (19.54194 50.06861)
3    POINT (19.34500 49.85528)
4    POINT (21.85400 50.88528)
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-6c6c8104c1e8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Dydaktyka/SIPwT (1z2)/test.py', wdir='D:/Dydaktyka/SIPwT (1z2)')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Dydaktyka/SIPwT (1z2)/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    postcodeGDF['geometry'] = postcodeGDF['geometry'].to_crs('+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 423, in to_crs
    proj_in = pyproj.Proj(self.crs, preserve_units=True)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 362, in __new__
    return _proj.Proj.__new__(self, projstring)

  File "_proj.pyx", line 129, in _proj.Proj.__cinit__

RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

Comment: That means there is something wrong with your pyproj installation. Can you give more details on how you installed GeoPandas and its dependencies? And can you show the output of `geopandas.show_versions()`?

Comment: @joris Thank you for the reply, I modified the original post (I didn't find another way to add new information)

Comment: Can you try if `conda update pyproj` helps? Also, how did you exactly install GeoPandas and its dependencies? (and updating your post was perfect!)

Comment: According to @joris advice I updated the pyproj module - didn't help.

I used Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64 installation file. As far as I remember I needed only to pip-install descartes module. pd, gpd, mplib, pyproj modules were already installed in original anaconda.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "didn't help". Do you still get the same error message, or another one? And what is the pyproj version you now have?

Comment: @joris, the pyproj version is 1.9.6. I inserted the results from console to the post.

Comment: That means that the `conda update pyproj` didn't work, I think (since the latest version is 2.4)

Comment: @joris, my anaconda navigator shows that there is an update available from my 1.9.6. However, when I start the procedure I obtain the report that "All requested packages already installed". Nothing changes, 1.9.6 remains. I tried to uninstall pyproj - anaconda demanded to uninstall a few other modules - agreed. I installed pyproj and lates version appeared. The problem is that my geopandas was unistalled also. When I install geopandas, it downgrades the pyproj to 1.9.6. Summing up, I cannot update the pyproj.